# What is this component? Marked XF 1A

Tags: diodes, identification

Help me identify the component on the board labeled XF 1A M with the designation VD13 on the board.

It's a diode, but which one (TVS, Shottky or another)?

Mounted in series in the +5V relay power line.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markings match with a [Vishay VS-15MQ040](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_Vishay-Intertech-VS-15MQ040NTRPBF_C428747.pdf) Schottky diode.

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Schottky-Barrier-Diodes-SBD_Vishay-Intertech-VS-15MQ040NTRPBF_C428747.html))

Answer (score 0):

https://www.s-manuals.com/smd/xf

According to above, there's a number of SMD devices with 'XF' marking.

This looks like SOD323, so this could be a zener diode from Nexperia (PZU20B3A). See datasheet: https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PZUXBA_SER.pdf

Comment: I don't think it's SOD323. It looks much bigger. Nexperia also uses a different marking style, I couldn't find a picture of PZU20B3A, but [here](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Zener-Diodes_Nexperia-PDZ10B-115_C85383.html) is an example of a SOD323 Nexperia zener diode. They all seem to look similar to this.

Comment: Dimensions correspond to DO-214AC (SMA) case.

Comment: @nanash1 Yes I think you're right, this probably isn't a nexperia part. Good idea to use lcsc for real photos of the components.